# Polymer - an error after putting application on the server

Tags: polymer

I finished my polymer project using polymer starter kit, everything was ok (on local server), without any errors, build was also successful but after I put my application on the server I cant open it - it returns me an error Uncaught TypeError:  Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null at my-app html:1, at line where i have polymer-element imported (the path is ok), and also one more error at one of the my-app subelements: Polymer is not a function, also at line 1, where I imported polymer-element. What could be a problem?

Comment: have you used Polymer 2.0? If yes can you please give me a sample. It may not be opening due to the windows.onload fires after your page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You probably faced the same issue as this guy from [Polymer Issues #958](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-starter-kit/issues/958). There are a few problems listed in the issue which could be relevant to your case:

1. Using Polymer version earlier than Polymer 2.0
2. Using an old version of Chrome
3. If you are using ES5 bundled version, perhaps you may not have included [custom-elements-es5-adapter.js](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs)

Ther are also some few other test cases, perhaps you should check out all of this first, then update your question.